# Sums of positive and negative distances to the least squares plane

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

Let $A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots, A_{n}$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $\pi_{*}$ be the least squares plane, i. e.

$$
\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n}\rho^{2}(A_{i}, \pi_{*}) = \min_{\pi}\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n}\rho^{2}(A_{i}, \pi)
$$

Is it true that

$$
\sum \limits_{i: \rho(A_{i}, \pi_{*}) > 0}|\rho(A_{i}, \pi_{*})| =
\sum \limits_{i: \rho(A_{i}, \pi_{*}) < 0}|\rho(A_{i}, \pi_{*})|
$$
?

Or can any other similiar proposition be proved about the sets of points with indices $\{i: \rho(A_{i}, \pi_{*}) > 0\}$ and $\{i: \rho(A_{i}, \pi_{*}) < 0\}$?

Can you advise any literature about these sets of points? Did any investigation ever been performed?

---

For points $(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, a)$ it is true. Evidently LS line is $y = y_{min}$, where $y_{min}$ minimizes the following functional:

$$
I(y) = y^{2} + y^{2} + (y - a)^{2}
$$
with $y_{min} = \frac{1}{3} a$. Hence, first sum is $\frac{2}{3} a$ and second sum is $\frac{1}{3} a + \frac{1}{3} a = \frac{2}{3} a$.

But I have doubt that it is true in general...

Comment: What is $\rho(\cdot)$? The distance from the plane?

Comment: Yes, it's signed distance to plane, i. e. $\rho(A, \pi) = \frac{a x_{A} + b y_{A} + c z_{A} + d}{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}}}$, where $A = (x_{A}, y_{A}, z_{A})$ and $\pi = \{a x + b y + c z + d = 0\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's true.

Plane $\pi_{*}$ is minimizing the following functional:

$$
I(a, b, c, d) = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{(a x_{i} + b y_{i} + c z_{i} + d)^{2}}{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}} \to inf
$$

thus

$$
\frac{\partial I}{\partial d} = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{2 (a x_{i} + b y_{i} + c z_{i} + d)}{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}}}\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{2 (a x_{i} + b y_{i} + c z_{i} + d)}{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}}} \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n} \rho(A_{i}, \pi) = 0
$$

that's why

$$
\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n} \rho(A_{i}, \pi_{*}) = 0
$$

and

$$
\sum \limits_{i: \rho(A_{i}, \pi_{*}) > 0}|\rho(A_{i}, \pi_{*})| =
\sum \limits_{i: \rho(A_{i}, \pi_{*}) < 0}|\rho(A_{i}, \pi_{*})|
$$